# How do I group and add values from nested hashes and arrays with same key?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am trying to get the sum of points and average grade for each student inside this combination of hashes and arrays but all my attempts only return the general sum for all entries. Any ideas?

```
student_data = 
  {"ST4"=>[{:student_id=>"ST4", :points=> 5, :grade=>5}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>10, :grade=>4}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>20, :grade=>5}], 
   "ST1"=>[{:student_id=>"ST1", :points=>10, :grade=>3}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST1", :points=>30, :grade=>4}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST1", :points=>45, :grade=>2}], 
   "ST2"=>[{:student_id=>"ST2", :points=>25, :grade=>5}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST2", :points=>15, :grade=>1}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST2", :points=>35, :grade=>3}], 
   "ST3"=>[{:student_id=>"ST3", :points=> 5, :grade=>5}, 
           {:student_id=>"ST3", :points=>50, :grade=>2}]}
```

Comment: What to do with _earning_ present ?

Comment: `”` & `"` differs and can give error in above code.

Comment: @ray, I've corrected those values. paco8, in future please test your input data before posting.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you expect can be achieved as below,

```
student_data.values.map do |z|
  z.group_by { |x| x[:student_id] }.transform_values do |v|
    { 
      points: v.map { |x| x[:points] }.sum, # sum of points
      grade: (v.map { |x| x[:grade] }.sum/v.count.to_f).round(2) # average of grades
    }
  end
end
```

As exact expected output format is not specified, obtained in following way,

```
=> [
  {"ST4"=>{:points=>35, :grade=>4.67}},
  {"ST1"=>{:points=>85, :grade=>3.0}},
  {"ST2"=>{:points=>75, :grade=>3.0}},
  {"ST3"=>{:points=>55, :grade=>3.5}}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired hash can be obtained thusly.

```
student_data.transform_values do |arr|
  points, grades = arr.map { |h| h.values_at(:points, :grade) }.transpose
  { :points=>points.sum, :grades=>grades.sum.fdiv(grades.size) }
end
  #=> {"ST4"=>{:points=>35, :grades=>4.666666666666667},
  #    "ST1"=>{:points=>85, :grades=>3.0},
  #    "ST2"=>{:points=>75, :grades=>3.0},
  #    "ST3"=>{:points=>55, :grades=>3.5}}
```

The first value passed to the block is the value of the first key, `'ST4'` and the block variable `arr` is assigned that value:

```
a = student_data.first
  #=> ["ST4",
  #    [{:student_id=>"ST4", :points=> 5, :grade=>5},
  #     {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>10, :grade=>4},
  #     {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>20, :grade=>5}]
  #   ] 
arr = a.last
  #=> [{:student_id=>"ST4", :points=> 5, :grade=>5},
  #    {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>10, :grade=>4},
  #    {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>20, :grade=>5}]
```

The block calculations are as follows. The first value of `arr` passed by `map` to the inner block is

```
h = arr.first
  #=> {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>5, :grade=>5} 
h.values_at(:points, :grade)
  #=> [5, 5]
```

After the remaining two elements of `arr` are passed to the block we have

```
b = arr.map { |h| h.values_at(:points, :grade) }
  #=> [[5, 5], [10, 4], [20, 5]]
```

Then

```
points, grades = b.transpose
  #=> [[5, 10, 20], [5, 4, 5]] 
points
  #=> [5, 10, 20] 
grades
  #=> [5, 4, 5]
```

We now simply form the hash that is the value of `'ST4'`.

```
c = points.sum
  #=> 35 
d = grades.sum
  #=> 14 
e = grades.size
  #=> 3 
f = c.fdiv(d)
  #=> 4.666666666666667
```

The value of `'ST4'` in `student_data` therefore maps to the hash

```
{ :points=>c, :grades=>f }
  #=> {:points=>35, :grades=>4.666666666666667}
```

The mappings of the remaining keys of `student_data` are computed similarly.

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at), [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose), [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) and [Integer#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv).

Answer (score 0):

For **Ruby 2.6** using [`Object#then`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview2/Object.html#method-i-then) or [`Object#yield_self`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) for **Ruby 2.5**

```
student_data.transform_values { |st| st
  .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, hh|  hh[:sum_points] += h[:points]; hh[:sum_grade] += h[:grade]; hh[:count] += 1.0 }
  .then{ |hh| {tot_points: hh[:sum_points], avg_grade: hh[:sum_grade]/hh[:count] } }
}
```

---

**How it works?**

Given the array for each student:

```
st = [{:student_id=>"ST4", :points=> 5, :grade=>5}, {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>10, :grade=>4}, {:student_id=>"ST4", :points=>20, :grade=>5}]
```

First build a hash adding and counting using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with a [`Hash#default`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview3/Hash.html#method-i-default) set at zero `(Hash.new(0)`)

```
step1 = st.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h, hh|  hh[:sum_points] += h[:points]; hh[:sum_grade] += h[:grade]; hh[:count] += 1.0 }
#=> {:sum_points=>35, :sum_grade=>14, :count=>3.0}
```

Then use then! (`yield_self` for Ruby 2.5)

```
step2 = step1.then{ |hh| {tot_points: hh[:sum_points], avg_grade: hh[:sum_grade]/hh[:count] }}
#=> {:tot_points=>35, :avg_grade=>4.666666666666667}
```

Put all together using [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) as in the first snippet of code